# How to combine my React state and another boolean

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, boolean

I have a banner in my react app which I can close:

I persist this state in localStorage:

```
  const [bannerShown, setBannerShown] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('MY_APP_STATE');

    if (data !== null) {
      setBannerShown(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('MY_APP_STATE', JSON.stringify(bannerShown));
  }, [bannerShown]);

  {bannerShown && (<MyBanner onClick={() => setBannerShown(false)} />)}
```

This is working fine. Now I want to *add* a condition:

I only want to show the banner when it contains a certain query param:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

const queryParams = queryString.parse(location.search);

const hasQueryParam = queryString
    .stringify(queryParams)
    .includes('foo=bar');
```

How do I combine above *state* and *boolean* (`hasQueryParam`) in a clean way?

Comment: ```{(bannerShown || hasQueryParam) && (<MyBanner onClick={() => setBannerShown(false)} />)}```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain together several statements in the JSX `{bannerShown && hasQueryParam && (<MyBanner onClick={() => setBannerShown(false)} />)}`

Or you could put this into an if statement

```
let showItem;
if (bannerShown && hasQueryParam) {
    showItem = <MyBanner onClick={() => setBannerShown(false)} />
}
```

Then in the JSX `{showItem}`

Comment: I wouldn't assign the component to a variable. Better approach might be:
```const showItem = bannerShown && hasQueryParam```
And in return statement use conditional render on that const

Answer (score -1):

set state true if query-string has any value

```
useEffect(() => {
const foo = qs.parse(location.search);
console.log(foo)
if(!Object.keys(foo).length === 0){
  setBanner(true)
}else{
  setBanner(false)
}
 }, [])
```